# R: Assign a value to a column inside a loop over rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looping over the rows of a dataframe

```
myDF$myCol <-NA

for(k in 1:nrow(myDF)){

   ...................

   myDF[k,][myCol] <- x
   }
```

but this gives me

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, myDF, value = 1) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

What is the problem in my code where I access the specific column of the each row in the loop

Comment: Difficult to tell without a reproducible example but from the error message it seems `myCol` has missing values (`NA`).

Comment: @RonakShah I edited the code. As I showed there, i assign NA before the loop

Comment: Try assigning `myDF[k,"myCol"] <- x` or `myDF[k,]["myCol"] <- x`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myDF$myCol = NA

for (k in 1:nrow(myDF)){
    myDF[k,'myCol'] = x
}
```